# Play local ismv file with MediaPlayer

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

I get a "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" anytime i try playing a local ismv file. Here is my code

```
 MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();

 mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri("To_The_Limit_720_230.ismv", UriKind.Relative);
 mediaPlayerLauncher.Location = MediaLocationType.Data;
 mediaPlayerLauncher.Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.Pause | MediaPlaybackControls.Stop;
 mediaPlayerLauncher.Orientation = MediaPlayerOrientation.Landscape;

 mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute`

```
mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri("To_The_Limit_720_230.ismv", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Add the following line

```
mediaPlayerLauncher.Location = MediaLocationType.Install;
```

Note:

```
mediaPlayerLauncher.Location = MediaLocationType.Data; // If you open media from isolated storage    
// (or)     
mediaPlayerLauncher.Location = MediaLocationType.Install; // If you open media from application project
```

Comment: Thanks Brainy, added the Location property only that I get the error "Sorry we can't play this file on your phone". It seems Media player cannot play the ismv file.

Comment: Yes, Media player cannot play the `ismv` file.

Comment: okay, what other option do i have to download and play smooth streaming contents offline

Comment: Consider using `Player Framework for Windows Phone 8 smooth streaming applications` http://playerframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%3A%20WP8%20Smooth%20Streaming%20Player

Answer (score 0):

Have u tryed to use UriKind.Absolute and give it the full path of the filedestination?

```
mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri(".../.../To_The_Limit_720_230.ismv", UriKind.Absolute);
```